# Force trigger of updating + updated events

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I noticed a model will not call the updating or updated event if there are no changes in the model. I guess it will compare `getOriginal` with `getDirty`.

However, when I'm updating only the relationship of a model, for example, attaching new categories, as this operation lives inside the updated event, it will never be triggered.

In this specific situation, the categories are dropped during updating event, and new ones attached during updated event. But it is only triggered if I change at least one value in the model.

Am I missing something?

This was not happening in 4.1, it is happening now with 4.2, composer updated today.

**Update:**

Here are the `updating` and `updated` events in the boot of my Product model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::updating(function($model)
    {
        $model->author_id = 1;//Auth::user()->id;

        $history = new ProductHistory($model->getOriginal());            
        $model->history()->save($history);

        $model->languages()->update(array(Product::$historyKey => $history->id));
        $model->currencies()->update(array(Product::$historyKey => $history->id));
        $model->paymentTypes()->update(array(Product::$historyKey => $history->id));
    }

    static::updated(function($model)
    {
        if(Input::has('languages')) $model->languages()->attach(Input::get('languages'));
        if(Input::has('currencies')) $model->currencies()->attach(Input::get('currencies'));
        if(Input::has('payment_types')) $model->paymentTypes()->attach(Input::get('payment_types'));
    }
}
```

And the `updating` event in the `BaseModel`:

```
    static::updating(function($model)
    {
        if(property_exists(get_class($model), 'rules'))
        {               
           if(!$model->validate()) return false;
        }
    });
```

This doesn't work anymore in 4.2, as the updating and updated events are ignored when there are no changes for the model. My *fix* was to use only `saving` and `saved` events, within these events I can identify if the model is being updated or created through checking if `getOriginal()`exists or not.

Comment: st your code that is responsible for the update.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Hi again Mr. Werewolf, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to trigger the parent model's `update` is just add the `$touches` property in the child model, for example, if you are updating the `ProductHistory` model which is the child of another model then just add following property in your `ProductHistory` model:

```
// Add this in ProductHistory model
protected $touches = array('Product');
```

Now everytime you update the `ProductHistory` it'll also update the `updated_at` field in it's parant model and in this case it's `Product` model, so the `updated_at` field will be updated and updated event will fire too and it makes sense to update the `updated_at` property of the parent model when it's child model is updated.

Check [Touching Parent Timestamps](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#touching-parent-timestamps) in `Laravel` website.

Comment: This looks good sir, but in this situation ProductHistory is being created inside updating event. Shouldn't `getOriginal()` return the models' relationships?